# How to output variables such as the current page's entry_id in the script tag

Tags: add-on, control-panel, javascript, variable, channel-files

One one of our sites, we have ChannelFiles add-on installed and in the control panel (when editing an entry) it outputs a useful set of variables (see attached). But this is only part of add-on and if it's not installed, those variables aren't outputted. Is there anyway I can output these variables without ChannelFiles?

Background: There are certain fields that I only want to ever appear when editing a specific entry so I include a bit of jquery in the field instruction to hide/show field by checking against the variables outputted by ChannelFiles add-on in the script tag.

http://imagebin.org/258416

Thanks

**UPDATE** (to clarify): I need this when editing the entry in the control panel of EE (see Background section on why) and not in the front end. As far as I know, I don't have access to the templates for the control panel (or do I?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can output entry ids from within the channel:entries tag pair like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="my_channel"}
  entry_id: {entry_id}<br>
{/exp:channel:entries
```

The [Channel Entries documenation at EllisLab](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#single-variables) provide all the variable options available to you.

**Update**

You can add this script to any of the field's Field Instructions section.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    entryId = (document.URL).split('entry_id=')[1].replace(/\D/g,'');
    $('.heading h2').append(' #' + entryId); // adds to heading at top of form
    alert("entry id = " + entryId);
  });
</script>
```

**Second Update**

The previous script wasn't removing numerical characters from the url that occurred after the entry_id. The problem is that EE encodes the `&` as `&amp;`. So here's this:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    firstPart = (document.URL).split('entry_id=')[0];
    entryId = (document.URL).split('entry_id=')[1].split(firstPart[firstPart.length -1])[0];
    $('.heading h2').append(' #' + entryId);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Second update works beautifully (although I don't really understand what's going on on this line: 

entryId = (document.URL).split('entry_id=')[1].split(firstPart[firstPart.length -1])[0];
). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd output the entry_id to the page as a hidden value, much as Stephen suggested, and then look to grab that with JavaScript. If you're viewing a specific entry_id for the page you're viewing then you made need to pass that in as a parameter:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="my_channel" entry_id="{entry_id}"}
    <p class="hidden">entry_id: {entry_id}</p>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

If you're just looking to use JS to show and hide specific fields depending on an entry ID however then you could do that purely on the server-side:

```
{if entry_id="10"} ... {/if}
```

This would have the benefit of being usable by those without JS enabled too.

Comment: Please see my update.

Comment: In the case of the CP the easiest way is a little 'hack' to [inject custom JS into the field instructions box](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/1552/how-to-add-a-custom-javascript-to-the-new-entry-control-panel). Just place your custom JS between script tags in there and it will run/output on the CP publish page.

Comment: That's what I am doing with the website that's running ChannelFiles add-on. Because the add-on outputs those variables in the entry edit pages (http://imagebin.org/258416) in the control panel, I can do a quick if-statement in JS to hide/show the field depending on the entry_id. My question is, on websites that aren't running ChannelFiles add-on, how can I have access to those same variables? I hope am making sense.