# Can I natively define a default value for a custom field?

Tags: ee2, custom-fields

I have a channel for events, which includes the time, date and city that the event is in. In approximately 80% of cases, the event's city will be Sydney.

Is it possible for me to define Sydney as the default value so that it's pre-filled when a user creates a new entry? I'm sure there's a relatively easy way to do this using a fieldtype or extension, however I would prefer to have this functionality natively.

Also, I guess you could do this on templates, using code such as:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="events" dynamic="no"}
  {if city}
    {city}
  {if:else}
    Sydney
  {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

but then I would have to remember to do this for every template that it occurs on, which is not ideal.

Cheers, for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not natively but you could throw a little JS into the field instructions as per [this question](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/1552/how-to-add-a-custom-javascript-to-the-new-entry-control-panel).

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    if (document.location.href.indexOf("entry_id") == -1) { // if it's a new entry
      var field = $("#field_id_15");
      if (field.val() == "") { field.val("Sydney"); }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Obviously just replace that with the appropriate ID of your field.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of [fieldtype](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/channels/custom_fields_edit.html#field-type) are using for cities? If it is a select fieldtype, you just need to put Sydney at the top of all options.

Comment: Good suggestion, cheers, though in this case I'd rather the user be able to enter any city he/she would like, rather than just choose from a set selection of cities

Answer (score 0):

If the fieldtype for city is simply a text field, one option would be to split it in two and use the awesome [entry typ](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/entry-type)e add-on to hide a custom field for an "other" city assignment.  So in the entry type field, you would have two values - "Sydney" and "Other". When Other is selected, a new text field would appear that would accept the other city value as a text field.  Or at least that's how you CAN set it up.  Then you would have a conditional very similar to what you're looking for.  Something like:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="events" dynamic="no"}
  {if city == "Other"}
    {other_city}
  {if:else}
    {city}
  {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Wherein the default value of {city} would be "Sydney", and {other_city} would come into play only if the value of {city} was selected to be "Other".  The entry type field can be radio button or dropdown list - and so dropdown list, with Sydney as the first option, would be a simple way to achieve what you're looking to do - and have it be quite user friendly to the site admins.

Hope that helps.