# Set new Matrix entry datepicker value to the current date

Tags: matrix, date

I would like to set the value of the date picker field to be the current date by default.  So every time I add a new row, i want that row to show the current date in the datepicker input field.

Thanks and let me know if you need any other information. I have the following code in my instructions field per [this post](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/1552/how-to-add-a-custom-javascript-to-the-new-entry-control-panel):

```
<script>
   document.getElementsByClassName('hasDatepicker').value = (new Date()).format("m/dd/yy");
</script>
```

But that doesn't seem to be working.

/* EDIT */
I tried to adjust my code a bit to see if that worked, but it didn't. I am trying to avoid JQuery just in case ther is a loading issue.

```
<script>
    document.getElementsByClassName(''matrix-add").addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.getElementsByClassName('event_helper_date').value = (new Date()).format("m/dd/yy");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: you want cell value to be current date? or when showing datepicker want it to display current date (datepicker shows current date by default) (also see: setDate and defaultDate) http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate

Comment: yeah, I want the actual input value to be the current date when a new input loads. Then they can change it if they want.  In this case 90% of the time it will just be the current date, but they want to save a step by having it default to that and then if they need to change it they can use the datepicker.