# CartThrob stock management for rentals/purchases

Tags: cartthrob

I've been looking into CartThrob as an eCommerce solution for a website we're going to be building which allows customers to rent the original artwork (stock of 1) for a specified amount of months or purchase the artwork outright, optionally with a specified amount of prints at different given sizes.

I've seen [another thread](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/2366/cartthrob-how-to-set-up-product-that-is-available-for-rent-or-purchase) which asked about purchases/rentals and the answers suggested using price modifiers to differentiate between a purchase and a rental which seems like the correct way to go, but is there a way to add custom data to the product if its a rental to say that it is on rental until a certain date and keep the stock count at 1, at which point the item is still available for rental and purchase but not until that date? I understand that this functionality is probably not available by default so I'm expecting to have to write an extension - would I use the [cartthrob_on_authorize](http://cartthrob.com/docs/developers/hooks/#cartthrob_on_authorize) hook to do post-checkout processing and set the data values accordingly? e.g. if its a rental then set the stock level back to 1?

There is also the possibility of their salesmen to have an app which should be able to create orders from a remote location (or save the orders to be later added when an internet connection is available) which I believe should be doable via a custom API which would use EE's [save_entry](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/api/api_channel_entries.html#save-entry) API method to insert an order with the specified products. Would adding order entries automatically adjust the stock levels if its a purchase (not a rental) and trigger the same hooks or would that have to be built into the custom API?