# Pre-populated content in Wygwam?

Tags: wygwam, custom-fields, textarea

Is it possible to have Wygwam (or any custom field) pre-populated with content when you create a new entry?

I'm aiming to give my client a table, with some cells already filled in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CKEditor (which is the editor used by Wygwam) has a feature called [Templates](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Templates) that you can use for this.

> With CKEditor content writers can select a template from a list by
>   clicking the Templates button in the toolbar. A template is a
>   predefined piece of HTML that is inserted into a document. Using this
>   feature, the user does not need to start formatting the text from
>   scratch. Designers can prepare well designed templates which helps
>   avoid user errors before they happen.

The end user would still need to click the templates button to get the boilerplate content. So it wouldn't pre-fill the entry immediately, but it would do so with one click.

---

Alternatively, take a look at these related questions for some other approaches. Or Jeremy's answer here in this post is great, too.

1) [Pre-populate a text input field](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/6529/pre-populate-a-text-input-field)

2) [Pre-fill matrix field when creating new entry?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/1548/pre-fill-matrix-field-when-creating-new-entry)

3) [Auto populate a field? (In this case a Matrix cell)](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/5439/auto-populate-a-field-in-this-case-a-matrix-cell/5451)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. But you could easily write a small custom accessory to do it with JavaScript.