# Save a Matrix fieldtype configuration to make it fixed and permanent for each entry of a channel

Tags: matrix, fieldtype

is there any solution to make permanent and repeat in each entry form a matrix fieldtype?

I would to make this set of field (includes row and colums) fixed for each new entry form in CP.

[image: Matrix field settings]
[image: Default matrix fieldtype]

In other words i want to save this matrix configuration of rows, columns and cells and repeat the same for each entry of a particular channel.

Is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help in write a script to Pre-fill matrix field when creating new entry](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9813/help-in-write-a-script-to-pre-fill-matrix-field-when-creating-new-entry)

Comment: I see you've already commented on http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/q/1548/150 - can you edit your question to explain what you've already tried, and what exactly you're stuck on?

Comment: You've also posted http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/q/9813/150 - please just write one question, with all the details we need. It makes it much easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to do this via the control panel you could create a 'default' entry and then use [MX Cloner](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-cloner) to duplicate it each time you create a new entry. That would start you off with all the Matrix data prepopulated on your duplicated entry.

Comment: this could be a solution, but there is no others solutions? i've asked this question, this could be another way.. [link](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9813/help-in-write-a-script-to-pre-fill-matrix-field-when-creating-new-entry)